# Audio to Video Sync Software

Tags: software

Hi:

I need an inexpensive software to sync audio to video.  I know ProTools in the standard but the cost is not in the budget yet.

Any suggestions?

Carmine

Answer (score 3):

Plural Eyes? http://www.singularsoftware.com/pluraleyes.html

I hear that the new version of Final Cut Pro has got the equivalent pre-installed.

Comment: PluralEyes has become kind of the standard for DSLR-based double-system sound sync. I've used it on a DSLR shoot or two, it's a huge timesaver. 

Comment: @Andrew Just downloaded and tried the trial for Vegas - works like a charm! I can't believe I have been doing this manually up till now. This should pay for itself in one job.  